# Error trying to display image: pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have the following image named `1.jpg` and try to display it:

[image]

but I get the following error message:

> pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image
>   Image not locate in Desktop.

This is my code so far:

```
import time
import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.jpg', grayscale=True))
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Dear all Plz solution for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
import pyautogui

image = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.jpg')
print(image)
```

Comment: Problem not resolve. Plz another solution. only desktop icon x&y coordinate recognization.